# Pseudo Random Number Generator test uniform distribution

Tags: random-number-generator

If I test the Pseudo Random Number Generator(PRNG) and it satisfies the **serial test**, it is not sure that the resulting distribution is uniform. Is my observation correct? If it is correct, what test should I do to be sure?

Comment: \[not an answer!\] I guess you consider this [serial test](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/legacy/sp/nistspecialpublication800-22r1a.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A448%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Fit%22%7D%5D). Are you looking for the [monobit test](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/legacy/sp/nistspecialpublication800-22r1a.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A141%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Fit%22%7D%5D)? That tests uniformity, but not independence of the bits. Nothing can reliably test the later.

Comment: I'm trying to understand mainly if the PRNG passes the serial test then it is not uniform distribution and why?

Comment: @fgrieu Standard permutation testing can identify independence :-)

Comment: @Paul Uszak: consider the PRNG based on a 64-byte hash $H$ (e.g. SHA-512) and 32-byte constant $C$, that given 32-byte seed $S$ first outputs 64-byte $R_0=H(C\mathbin∥S)$, then 64-byte $R_{i+1}=H(C\mathbin∥R_i)$. New output $R_{i+1}$ is dependent on $R_i$, and nothing else variable. Yet no test will identify that, or otherwise distinguish from random the outputs of the PRNG for different seeds, unless the test somehow knows $C$. Testing can sometime identify dependence. Does that mean _"testing can identify independence"_? You decide on that semantic issue.

Comment: @fgrieu Oh I see! I thought that you were referring to the output sequence since we're talking about tests on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the question is about this [serial test](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/legacy/sp/nistspecialpublication800-22r1a.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A448%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Fit%22%7D%5D).

> If I test a [Pseudo Random Number Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) (PRNG) and it satisfies the serial test, it is not sure that the resulting distribution is uniform.

**Yes**. No test on the output of a PRNG is able to make one *sure* of anything about the distribution of the output of the PRNG, for the mathematical definition of sure. Argument: it's possible that the PRNG outputs 0 starting at the $2^{160}$-th bit that it outputs, and it's trivial to make such PRNG that passes all practical tests ever devised. I admit this argument of correctness of the quoted proposition is not helpful.

For something more helpful, we must reach some functional interpretation of *"sure that the resulting distribution is uniform"*. For a start, we should decide if this shall hold for a PRNG which computes it's first output bit from the seed, then always outputs the complement of the previous output bit (so that it's output is either `0101010101…` or `1010101010…` depending on the seed).

1. If we accept that for such pathological PRNG *"the resulting distribution is uniform"* can hold (perhaps, according to how the first bit is computed), then we are interested only in the *frequency* of bits in the output. The best possible test on the output of a PRNG for the property that we want is the [monobit test](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/legacy/sp/nistspecialpublication800-22r1a.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A141%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Fit%22%7D%5D).
2. Otherwise, our interpretation of *"sure that the resulting distribution is uniform"* likely is that we want assurance that the output bits of the PRNG are indistinguishable form a uniform distribution of *independent* bits.

For both meanings, **the quoted proposition is true if parameter $m\ge2$ in the serial test**. That parameter defines the length of the bit subsequences which frequency is assessed. Argument: it's possible to construct a PRNG which output sequences for a given (nontrivial) length both reliably pass the serial test, but reliably fail the monobit test. The idea is that the subsequences of $m$ bits have a distribution within the tolerance of the serial test, but overall the bias of individual bits is above the threshold of the monobit test.

For $m=1$ the serial test aims at being equivalent to the monobit test, and I think it is; that would arguably make the proposition false for meaning 1 and $m=1$.

For meaning 2, the proposition is true because it's impossible to experimentally reach the desired conclusion by any test on the output of a PRNG, even if we accept a high residual probability of falsely reaching that conclusion (say, 25%). Argument: even if many PRNG tests succeed, it's always possible that the output sequence(s) of the PRNG have some regularity that escape these tests, but is caught by a test tailored to the internals of the PRNG. The best a PRNG test can do is *disprove*, within an extremely small residual probability of the contrary (say, 0.01%), that *"the resulting distribution is uniform"* for meaning 2; and that can occur only when the test fails.

> What test should I do to be sure?

Again, for meaning 1, the monobit test is the best there is. And even if that passes, you can't be sure.

For meaning 2, no test on the output of a PRNG can give a meaningful assurance (much less certainty) *"that the resulting distribution is uniform"*. Only examining the construction of the PRNG can give such assurance.